# How to fetch all posts in a category that were published between two given dates?

Tags: query-posts

I need to be able to get all posts in the blog that were published in between two dates. The get_posts() API call doesn't seem to provide a method for limiting the time period of the returned results to a particular date range.

If this isn't available, how could this be done through direct queries. I've attempted to do this directly but I am not able to find where in the database are the columns and rows that correspond to the categorization of blog posts in a particular category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, both involve `WP_Query`.

1. No Hooks

   Unfortunately, this is the less flexible way of doing things, but it is the way which is built into `WP_Query`.  With the default `WP_Query` time parameters, you can get all the posts for a given numerical date. For example, all the posts from 2011, or all the posts from the 3rd month, or all the posts from this calendar week, etc. You can also do permutations thereof (so all the posts from the 3rd month of 2011).  Unfortunately, this can leave a lot to be desired.
2. Hooks

   With the `posts_where` hook, it is possible to filter by `post_date`.  You will need to write the SQL you want to ADD (and I stress, ADD) to the `WHERE` portion of the query by hand, so for example:

   ```
   wpse51235_posts_where( $where ) {
       $where .= ' AND post_date < blah AND post_date > blah2 ';
       return $where;
   }
   ```

   Note that it opens and closes with a ' ', in addition to opening with an AND. This is to ensure that if some other code doesn't open with a space, the whole query will not break. There's no way to have too many spaces.